# Особенности глобальных переменных

Tags: c++, c, переменные, объявление

- Как распространить видимость глобальной переменной на два файла?
- Может ли в блоке быть объявлена extern-переменная для расширения области видимости глобальной переменной?
- Можно ли внутри блока изменять значение глобальной переменной?
- Могут ли имена глобальной переменной и переменной, определенной внутри блока, совпадать?
- Могут ли несколько файлов иметь глобальную переменную с одинаковым именем?

Comment: Пожалуйста, задавайте один вопрос в одной публикации (вопросе).

Answer (score 4):

> Как распространить видимость глобальной переменной на два файла?

Нужно поместить объявление переменной со спецификатором `extern`  в заголовочный файл, и включить этот заголовок в два файла с кодом. При этом определить переменную следуют только в одном файле.

> Может ли в блоке быть объявлена extern-переменная для расширения
>   области видимости глобальной переменной?

В C++ вы можете использовать квалифицированное имя переменной, указывая перед именем переменной имя пространства имен, где переменная объявлена. Например, если переменная `x`  объявлена в глобальном пространстве имен, то для обращения к ней вы можете использовать имя `::x`.

Вы также можете в C и в C++ объявить внешнюю переменную в блоке кода, снабдив объявление спецификатором `extern`.

> Можно ли внутри блока изменять значение глобальной переменной?

Если переменная не объявлена с c/v квалификатором, то вы можете ее изменять.

> Могут ли имена глобальной переменной и переменной, определенной внутри
>   блока, совпадать?

Как уже было упомянуто, в C++ для глобальной переменной вы можете использовать квалифицированное имя, благодаря чему оно будет отличаться от имени локальной переменной. В противном случае имя локальной переменной будет скрывать имя глобальной переменной.

> Могут ли несколько файлов иметь глобальную переменную с одинаковым
>   именем?

Если переменная имеет внутреннее связывание, то в каждой единице трансляции эта переменная будет представлять отдельный объект. Если же она имеет внешнее связывание, то все переменные, объявленные с тем же именем и внешним связыванием будут обозначать один и тот же объект.

В заключении пример простой программы, в которой поведение переменных, объявленных со спецификатором `extern` , в языках C и C++ совпадают

```
#include <iostream>

extern int x = 10;

int main() 
{
    std::cout << "x = " << x << std::endl;

    {
        int x = 20;

        std::cout << "x = " << x << std::endl;

        {
            extern int x;

            x = 30;

            std::cout << "x = " << x << std::endl;
        }

        std::cout << "x = " << x << std::endl;

    }       

    std::cout << "x = " << x << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль

```
x = 10
x = 20
x = 30
x = 20
x = 30
```

Comment: «Если переменная не объявлена с c/v квалификатором» — вроде ж только c, v мешать не должно?

Comment: @VladD Для volatile переменной вы, как клиент, можете читать ее значения, но не присваивать значения.

Comment: А можно какую-нибудь ссылку на любую документацию? А то я, к своему стыду, должен признаться, что слышу об этом в первый раз. Например, [тут](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv) ничего об этом не нашёл.

Comment: @VladD Обычно как изменяется объект с квалификатором volatile , неизвестно клиенту, использующему эту переменную. Поэтому изменять этот объект клиенту может иметь непредсказуемый эффект.

Comment: Ага, теперь понял, спасибо!

Comment: @VladD  Помимо этого есть некоторая симметрия с квалификатором const. Например, (стандарт С) "If an attempt is made to refer to an object deﬁned with a volatile-qualiﬁed type through use of an lvalue with non-volatile-qualiﬁed type, the behavior is undeﬁned.".