# с++/с Нужна помощь

Tags: c++, c

Могут ли несколько файлов иметь функции с одинаковым именем и сигнатурой? 
Можно ли в файле использовать глобальную переменную, определенную в другом файле?
Можно ли во вложенном блоке определить переменную с таким же идентификатором, как у переменной во внешнем блоке?
Как ограничить область использования глобальной переменной одним файлом? 
Может ли переменная в приложении быть объявлена исключительно с классом памяти extern?

Comment: Большинство их этих вопросов являются бессмысленной самопротиворечивой терминологической кашей. Что такое "иметь функции"? Иметь объявления? Или определения? "Ограничить область использования глобальной переменной одним файлом" невозможно, ибо тогда эта переменная уже не будет глобальной. "Исключительно с классом памяти extern"? У любой переменной всегда исключительно только один класс памяти. По-другому не бывает. В чем смысл упоминания "исключительности"?

Comment: @Zolberg N  Вы уже задали похожий вопрос. Зачем вы тиражируете вопросы?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Переменные(help)](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/633877/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5help)

Comment: "С одинаковым именем и сигнатурой" - но в С++ имя и так входит в сигнатуру. Что тогда такое "с именем И сигнатурой"? А в С нет понятия сигнатуры функции.

Answer (score 2):

**Могут ли несколько файлов иметь функции с одинаковым именем и сигнатурой?**
  Если оба файла входят в одно приложение - нет.

**Можно ли в файле использовать глобальную переменную, определенную в другом файле?**
   Можно. См. атрибут *external*

**Можно ли во вложенном блоке определить переменную с таким же идентификатором, как у переменной во внешнем блоке?**
   Можно.

**Как ограничить область использования глобальной переменной одним файлом?** 
  См. атрибут *static*

**Может ли переменная в приложении быть объявлена исключительно с классом памяти extern?**
   Что значит "исключительно" ? А вообще - может. Например:

```
extern int errno;
```

Comment: Касательно первого вопроса: кажется, если мы объявим такие ф-ии с модификатором static - все будет работать, каждую такую ф-ию будет "ограничивать" ее единица трансляции.

Comment: Да, разумеется Вы правы!